# Где можно посмотреть код jdk классов?

Tags: java, openjdk

Возникла необходимость найти коды jdk классов! 
 *Где и как можно это сделать?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это очень просто сделать через IDE. Например в IDEA, можно через Ctrl+Лкм по любому классу.

Пример из перехода на String

```
public final class String     //Тут не полный код.
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    /** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];

    /** Cache the hash code for the string */
    private int hash; // Default to 0

    /** use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.0.2 for interoperability */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6849794470754667710L;
```

Answer (score 3):

Скачивайте с официального сайта [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)  и просматривайте локально. Либо просматривайте [онлайн](http://grepcode.com)